# Issue while implementing json_exists using JPA Native query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My Query looks like below,

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM Retention_Record retention where retention.entity=:entity and retention.category=:category and retention.record_type=:recordType and json_exists(retention.reference_data_id, '$?(@==$referenceDataId)' passing :referenceDataId as \"referenceDataId\")" , nativeQuery=true)
```

When i am getting below error while execution of this query

```
2020-07-23 16:12:11 [eventsTaskExecutor-5] [] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 29902, SQLState: 99
999
2020-07-23 16:12:11 [eventsTaskExecutor-5] [] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-29902: error in executing
ODCIIndexStart() routine
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-50900: text query parser error on line 1, column 10
DRG-50917: escape on at end of text query string
```

Can anyone please help.

Comment: Does it work in Oracle database?

Comment: yes... on oracle db it works.

Comment: Can you share that query as well?

Comment: Hi @MuhammadWaqasDilawar,  SELECT * FROM Retention_Record retention where retention.entity=? and retention.category=? and retention.record_type=? and json_exists(retention.reference_data_id, '$?(@==$referenceDataId)' passing ? as "referenceDataId" )

Comment: Also, this works, but the query in question does not.  <br />  ```@Query(value="SELECT * FROM Retention_Record retention where retention.entity=:entity and retention.category=:category and retention.record_type=:recordType and json_exists(retention.reference_data_id, '$?(@==50000021)' )" , nativeQuery=true)```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. Problem was with the way i was storing the Json Object in database. I was storing the value in db as ["50000021","50000022"] which in fact is a valid json, and was trying to execute my query to provide result, which was resulting in error. When i stored data in this format, { "ReferenceDataId" : ["50000021","50000022"] } below query successfully executed. – Ritesh 1 min ago   Edit   Delete

`@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Retention_Record retention where retention.entity=:entity and retention.category=:category and retention.record_type=:recordType and json_exists(retention.reference_data_id, '$.ReferenceDataId?(@==$referenceDataId)' passing :referenceDataId as \"referenceDataId\")", nativeQuery = true)`